# Issue is installing sensu agent in container

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops, monitoring, sensu

I need to monitor the instance and the container running on it. How can I configure the Sensu agent for that? Is installing the Sensu agent on the instance enough to monitor both the instance and the container?

I have installed sensuagent in instance and run sensu-agent as a side car to monitor contianer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.